I've been/I was called into work
Scenario #1:
John's boss calls him and tells him that he wants him in the office in two hours because something urgent has come up. Ten minutes later, John's girlfriend calls and suggests they go to the movies tonight. John replies:
1A. Sorry, I've been called into work, but I'm up for it tomorrow. What do you say?
2A. Sorry, I've [gotten - AmE]/[got - BrE] called into work, but I'm up for it tomorrow. What do you say?
Scenario #2:
John's boss calls him and tells him that he wants him in the office in two hours because something urgent has come up. By the time John is already at the office working (three hours since his boss's call), his girlfriend calls and suggests they go to the movies tonight. John replies:
1B. Sorry, I was called into work, but I'm up for it tomorrow. What do you say?
2B. Sorry, I got called into work, but I'm up for it tomorrow. What do you say?
Question:
Are the tenses in bold used correctly in the above two scenarios, and are the verbs "be" and "get" both possible in this context? Thanks.

Not being a British-English speaker I'm not sure, but I think it's unlikely to use any form of "got," and more likely to say "I've been called into work."

Present prefect is always  relevant to/at the time of speaking. Simple past is always finished/over. Yes, get called/was called (passives) and many action verbs: got burned, was burned. And on and on. For me, I've gotten called into work, I have to go right now. is AmE. BrE would merely be: I've got called into work. [the use of got instead of gotten] There are tons of questions on here about this.

To me (AmE), "I've been called into work" seems more natural.

And in Scenario 2, any of 1A, 1B, or 2B would be fine.

@Barmar  As a BrE speaker that works for me too.

Foe scenario 2, I think A1 is still the best fit.

As another BrE speaker, I've got called sounds clunky and unnatural.
